# Spring Security keeps redirecting to http when on https

Tags: apache, tomcat, spring-mvc, ssl, spring-security

After I login or logout, Spring keeps redirecting me to a http page.  Adding `requires-channel="https"` to pages just causes a redirect loop.  This works fine on my local computer, but this project is setup under apache and a load balancer.

```
<http pattern="/services/**" create-session="stateless"
        entry-point-ref="basicAuthAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <http-basic />
        <port-mappings>
            <port-mapping http="8009" https="8443"/>
            <port-mapping http="80" https="443"/>
       </port-mappings>
       <intercept-url pattern="/services/**" access="ROLE_SERVICE" />
    </http>

    <http auto-config="true">
        <port-mappings>
            <port-mapping http="8009" https="8443"/>
            <port-mapping http="80" https="443"/>
        </port-mappings>
        <intercept-url pattern="/index.*" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/welcome.htm" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/changePassword.htm" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/notifications/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/logging/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login login-page="/login.htm" default-target-url="/welcome.htm"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed.htm" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout.htm" />
    </http>
```

Comment: Your apache, tomcat and load balancer configurations are essential information here. If you are using a reverse proxy I wouldn't use Spring Security's port mappings at all. You should be able to get it working just between your Tomcat and your Apache configurations. You'll need to spend some time looking at how browser requests are handled the especially how redirects are rewritten.

Comment: Well it posts to spring_security_check via https and then does a 301 redirect to the http landing page.

Comment: I meant a 302 redirect